# Entity framework 4.1 relation to table itselft

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

is there anyone who could tell me how can i do the corresponding table mapping with entity framework code first.
Here is my table

[enter link description here](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4890/matiere.png)

i've tried to do this but without any success.

```
[Table("Matiere")]
public class Matiere
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32? IdParent { get; set; }
    [Column("NomMatiere")]
    public String Nom { get; set; }
    public virtual Matiere Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Matiere> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class MatiereConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Matiere>
{
    public MatiereConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasOptional(m => m.Parent).WithMany(m => m.Childs).HasForeignKey(m => m.IdParent);
        this.HasOptional(m => m.Childs).WithRequired();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. I do not think you need to supply the `HasOptional(m => m.Childs).WithRequired();`

First, I would put all of your mapping information into your MatiereConfiguration instead of using a mix of DataAnnotations and Fluent mappings. It's not required, but just a suggestion.

This should work:

```
    public class MatiereConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Matiere>
    {
        public MatiereConfiguration()
        {
          HasKey(m => m.Id);
          Property(m => m.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
          Property(m => m.Nom).HasColumnName("NomMatiere")           
          HasOptional(m => m.Parent).WithMany(m => m.Childs).HasForeignKey(m => m.IdParent);

        }
    }
```